# c# app + upload video to Youtube

Tags: c#, upload, youtube-api

I need to create a c# application where I  can upload a video ( I give the path for the video which is .mp4)  to Youtube.

How can I do that? I need to add a reference in my project of Google Data .NET Client library and  I also have to obtain a Developer key.

In order to add reference such as:

```
using Google.GData.Client; 

// I need to have a method authentificate :     
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = 
     new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey);
YouTubeRequest request = 
     new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

Also if I have the video .mp4 do I need to have a model for uploading it on youtube? Model such Tile, Description....?

Moreover in order to add reference suh as Google Data Core API LIBRARY I need to build Google Data api sdk . In order to do that, I need to add reference to Nunit. but for moment, the download site doesn't work. I do need to build the sdk in order to add reference to my project , right?

Need help please

Comment: You've pretty much already answered your own questions. Yes, you should use the Google API and need a key for your application. It's all laid out in great detail in the YouTube Developer's Guide: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Answer (score 3):

once you have downloaded the library you mentioned, Google Data .NET, here is a snippet to upload a video from a local file, you should include such snippet in your application.

```
Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title ="My Test Movie";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
newVideo.Description = "My description";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", 
  YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
// alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
// newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\file.mov",
  "video/quicktime");
Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

For extensive documentation and samples refer to the official, public, .NET Developer's Guide: [YouTube APIs and Tools - Developer's Guide: .NET](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Direct_Upload)